# Canonical question about the JavaScript supported version by Google Apps Script

Tags: discussion, questions, canonical

Earlier this year Google launched a new runtime for Google Apps Script, Chrome V8, which is the default for new projects. This new runtime supports most of the features of ECMAScript 6 but not all (i.e. Promises aren't supported).

---

There are several questions asking for the JavaScript / ECMAScript supported version by Google Apps Script

Below is small sample of my findings, sorted by oldest first

- [Is there a complete definition of the Google App Script Syntax somewhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12279357/1595451) Score: 6, Linked: 7
- [Which Edition of ECMA-262 Does Google Apps Script Support?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17252409/1595451) Score: 25, Linked: 9
- [Which JavaScript features are available in Google Apps scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27280399/1595451) Score: 1, Linked: 0
- [Google Apps Script Javascript Standard Support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37768501/1595451) Score: 4, Linked: 5
- [How do I find which version of JavaScript my web browser supports?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42600329/1595451) Score: 0, Linked: 1

---

Also there are several question about JavaScript features that are not working as expected by Google Apps Script

- [How do I format this date string so that google scripts recognizes it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11810441/1595451) Score: 11, Linked: 3
- [Google Apps Script (in Google Sheets) behaves differently from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29457735/1595451) Score: 1, Linked: 0
- [What functions do Arrays in Google Apps Script support?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39317252/1595451) Score: 13, Linked: 1
- [JS syntax error while building object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45899020/1595451) Score: 0, Linked: 1
- [The script is working fine, but not in 'google-apps-script'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47190499/1595451) Score: 0, Linked: 0
- [Google Apps Script Redeclaration of Const Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48293261/1595451) Score: 5, Linked: 1
- [Declaring variables on Google sheet script editor using let](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48654622/1595451) Score: 2, Linked: 1
- [Simple Javascript code not working in Google docs due to arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51626679/1595451) Score: -1, Linked: 1
- [Google Apps Script throws error when trying to call Object.assign()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51878527/1595451) Score: 1, Linked: 3

[Which Edition of ECMA-262 Does Google Apps Script Support?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17252409/1595451) has the higher score and number of linked questions. Should it be used as the "canonical question" to mark the other questions as duplicate of it and used as reference on questions about JavaScript features don't working as expected?

Comment: 10 ?SYNTAX ERROR

Comment: The canonical answer is here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features

Comment: @Braian Before posting this question I posted a quotation of that source as answer to [Google Apps Script Javascript Standard Support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37768501/1595451)

Answer (score 3):

[Which Edition of ECMA-262 Does Google Apps Script Support?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17252409/1595451) now has a score of 34 and 14 linked questions  so it looks to me that it's is the de-facto canonical question.

The Mogsdad's answer has a score of 29 and have recently updated with the following statement

> **Edit II**: As of May 2020, Google Apps Script is supported by the V8 runtime. Because of this, [Apps Script is no longer tied to a specific ECMAScript version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime).

New follow up question: [Is it OK to remove obsolete content from canonical answers that have updated by adding EDIT / UPDATE labels?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398309/1595451)

Comment: So, it's where my comment said it was? Color me unsurprised.

Comment: @Braiam Your comment "is in another castle" :)

Comment: It's actually in this question :) See Jan 31 '19 comment.