# Is it OK to remove obsolete content from canonical answers that have updated by adding EDIT / UPDATE labels?

Tags: discussion, answers, canonical, editing-help

Some "old" answers that became obsolete over the time in an attempt to keep them up to date were edited to include relevant changes.

Here is one example

> The [current documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features) (June 2013) says Apps Script provides a
> subset of [ECMAScript 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) and is based on [JavaScript 1.8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.8).
>
> **Edit:** Google has backtracked somewhat. As of Nov 2013, they are reporting that Apps Script is based on 1.6, with a smattering of 1.7
> and 1.8.
>
> **Edit II**: As of May 2020, Google Apps Script is supported by the V8 runtime. Because of this, [Apps Script is no longer tied to a specific
> ECMAScript version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime).

The above answer has a score of 30, and it' a de-facto canonical answer for questions asking which JavaScript version is supported by Google Apps Script but there are several answers in the same situation:

1. The answer is old and was "correct" at the time it was created.
2. Over the time it become obsolete. Sometimes the answer author, sometimes someone else in an attempt to update the answer added something new like a change on the platform, a link to a recent bug fix report, or a new code snippet including a recently added feature
3. The new content includes an **EDIT** / **UPDATE** label.
4. The obsolete content is kept in the answer's body

Is it OK to remove the obsolete content and just to keep the last "edit", i.e.,

> As of May 2020, Google Apps Script is supported by the V8 runtime. Because of this, [Apps Script is no longer tied to a specific ECMAScript version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime).

Related

- [Canonical question about the JavaScript supported version by Google Apps Script](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379573/1595451)

Comment: If and only if it is impossible for said "obsolete content" to be useful to someone today.

Comment: Historians / archivists could look for the obsolete content in the revision history :)

Comment: IMO, the content shouldn't be removed, but the most recent should be the most prominent. Convert it into a timeline of sorts, with the current answer up front, and then noting that the support changed on date X, Y, and Z.

Comment: I don't know a good solution but one thing I do find annoying is "... long answer ... **UPDATE** better answer ... **EDIT** even better answer ...". I think I prefer the best (current) answer at the top – just like votes.

Comment: Problem is the difference between obsolete and "not current version".  I have a feeling that way to many people would use obsolete incorrectly when an answer doesn't apply to the current version.  The issue becomes when you have completely obsolete because of technology changes rendered the answer to not work at all.  Vs an older version of the language which is still used by anyone who is forced to support an older language

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I genuinely believe that one would use ["obsolete"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obsolete) as "replaced by newer" and not necessarily not working. That said, though, I would agree that the "timeline" update or a notice that the feature / doc is obsolete is a better alternative in how SO works currently. Though, in cases where we could come to terms with OP about updating the answer, I argue in favour of moving obsolete content to history - after all, when using VCS we see the *latest* version with an *option* to inspect commit history, not the whole tree